# How to create a ASP.NET Website patch?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, sql-server-2012

One of my Asp.net website has gone live recently and we are getting few issues in early stage. We have to release new build after every 5-7 days to get customers working.

Now I am want to ensure if anything goes wrong with new change for few customers while working fine for many others then new feature can be switched OFF for customers that are facing issue with new change. 
**Note : Every company(customer) has its own database while sharing a single website URL i.e. Company Specific database is getting connected after log in of user to website.**

Can you please suggest me anything for developing new feature or changing existing feature to be option based (Switched ON|OFF)?So that we can get time to fix it properly without reverting the whole website to previous build.Sorry if I am not able to explain it properly.

We need to switch OFF website and database changes both.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Krishan

Comment: Your question raises a lot of new questions. Can you narrow down your issue to a specific question? Switching code on and off is easy, you can for example easily add an appSettings-key/value-pair like `featureXEnabled=true` and check that from code.

Comment: The quick answer is: use the config to configure the site. A longer answer is too broad. (PS. I would strongly suggest using a Web App project, Web Sites are just a pain to work with.)

Comment: Hi Richard, Please give me idea, How a web project will help to achieve my requirement.